# I want to make electricity of aluminiun cans i.e. reverse the process of refinning aluminium. Any ideas?

Tags: electrochemistry

Recycling Al cans to produce electricity,i.e. to reverse the process of electrolysis and produce electricity

Comment: Since you can make good money just recycling the aluminium (because you thereby avoid the electricity required to make it) this doesn't sound very economically viable.

Comment: There is a company whose claim to fame is this exact process(Phinergy). Make aluminum where energy is available, e.g. Alcoa plant near Niagara Falls, and oxidize it elsewhere when necessary.  http://triblive.com/business/headlines/7431480-74/battery-aluminum-alcoa , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium%E2%80%93air_battery

Answer (score 3):

You could "burn" the aluminum in the presence of oxygen to generate aluminum oxide.  For every two moles of aluminum consumed, a bit less than 1700 kJ of energy would be released.  You could use the energy to drive a turbine and generate electricity.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with using aluminum from cans, as they are coated with a thin layer of plastic to prevent them from reacting.  That will tend to interfere with any chemistry you might want to do to the aluminum inside.  If that's not an issue, it's pretty straightforward to do, if not economical in the slightest.

There's nothing to prevent you from setting up a [galvanic cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell) with aluminum at the anode and a metal salt with a reduction potential greater than -1.6V at the cathode.  I've made cells using aluminum foil and copper chloride in the past, for example, though I wouldn't recommend them for electricity production.

That's not to say that there isn't promise for aluminum's use in batteries.  Researchers at Stanford U published a [paper in Nature](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v520/n7547/full/nature14340.html) in early 2016 about an aluminum-ion battery with good voltage that could be recharged repeatedly and that charged in about 1 minute.